# Prove the existence of degree at most 2 given certain conditions

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Let $f: \mathbb{R\rightarrow R}$ be a $C^2$ function. Show that there exists a unique polynomial $Q$ of degree at most 2 such that $P(0)=f(0), P'(0)=f'(0)$ and  $P''(0)=f''(0)$.

How would one prove such a statement? This is a little bit beyond the difficulty level of what we have done in class but I want to understand it for my own sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lose uniqueness if you go to degree 3 or higher. Otherwise you just have the following system. The degree $2$ curve is $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$. $P(0) = c = f(0)$. Then also $P'(0) = b = f'(0)$. Lastly $P''(0) = 2a = f''(0)$. So in fact no solving is necessary. All I did was write down the polynomial and differentiate it.

To show uniqueness fails, we can play the same game with a cubic $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = 0$. Then $P(0) = d = f(0)$, and $P'(0) = c = f'(0)$, and $P''(0) = 2b = f''(0)$, but this system fails to determine $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume

$$P(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$

then

$$P(0)=f(0)\implies c=f(0)$$

$$P'(0)=f'(0)\implies b=f’(0)$$

$$P''(0)=f''(0) \implies 2a=f’’(0)$$

Comment: This is the same as my answer :P

Comment: repetita juvant ;)